# Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException when trying to upload file to AWS

Tags: amazon-s3, php-8

I have a problem with php 8, the code that I show works perfectly in php5 but in php 8 it shows me an error and I don't know how to solve it.

```
    $s3 = S3Client::factory(
                        array(
                            'credentials'   => array(
                                'key'       => IAM_KEY,
                                'secret'    => IAM_SECRET
                            ),
                            'version' => 'latest',
                            'region'  => 'eu-west-1'
                        )
                    );
$s3->putObject(
                    array(
                        'Bucket'        => RUTA_REPOSITORIO,
                        'Key'           => $_FILES['Archivo_'.$i]['name'],
                        'SourceFile'    => $_FILES['Archivo_'.$i]['tmp_name']
                        //'Body'            => $_FILES['Archivo_'.$i]['tmp_name']
                    )
                );
```

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Guzzle\Common\Exception\InvalidArgumentException

Message: Invalid handle provided

Comment: A newer guzzle should fix the issue. can you try it

Comment: I have read that it may be because of that but I don't know how to update it, I use codeigniter and I have a folder with the contents of guzzle but I don't know where to look for the new version and download the folder to change it to the one I have

Comment: I think you are using AWS PHP SDK v2, you can try to run the `compatibility-test.php` file in the SDK to quickly check if your system is capable of running the SDK with php8. The compatibility test can output text for the command line or a web browser. Bdw AWS PHP SDKs has now a newer version available to use so you may think to upgrade :)

Comment: @Arpit jainista its Is it possible to contact you by email?